# remove empty parenthesis from expression

Tags: javascript, regex, parentheses

I want to remove those parenthesis which are empty from expression in javascript regular expression. For e.g  `(() a and b)` -> `( and b)`. It should also work for the case `( (  (  ()  )  )a and b)` -> `(a and b)`. Basicaly it should remove unnecessary parenthesis from expression. I am writng reguar expression

```
expression.replace(/(\s)/,'');
```

but this is not working. Can anyone help ?

Comment: I think you want to replace `(() a and b)` and `( (  (  ()  )  )a and b)` with `( a and b)`. See the space after `(` and `a` (it is missing in the first expected output).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```js
const text = "( (  (  ()  )  )a and b)";
let output = text;
while (output != (output = output.replace(/\(\s*\)/g, ""))); 
console.log(output);
```

The `/\(\s*\)/g` regex matches all non-overlapping occurrences of

- `\(` - a literal `(` char
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespace chars
- `\)` - a literal `)` char.

The `while (output != ...)` loop makes sure the replacement occurs as many times as necessary to remove all substrings between open/close parentheses until no more matches are found.

Answer (score 2):

There are different ways to do this, a simple, iterative one is to repeatedly remove emtpy parentheses (need to be escaped in regex!):

```
function remove_empty_parens(str) {
    let new_str = str.replace(/\(\s*\)/, '');
    return new_str == str ? str : remove_empty_parens(new_str);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `/\(\s*\)/` to remove unnested pairs:

- Escape the parentheses using `\(` and `\)` because they have a special meaning in regexps.
- Allow zero or more whitespace characters instead of just one, using `\s*`.

However, you cannot remove nested parentheses this way using a truly regular expression, as a consequence of the [pumping lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_regular_languages). Regexps in JavaScript aren't "regular" expressions in the theoretical sense, so maybe something can be done (for example with backreferences), but I don't immediately see it.

One possible solution is to repeatedly apply the above regexp until the string no longer changes.

Answer (score 0):

This example run for me:

```js
let expression1 = "( (  (  ()  )  )a and b)"

let last_expression1 = ""
let regex = /(\(\ *\))+/g;
while (expression1 != last_expression1) {
  last_expression1 = expression1
  expression1 = expression1.replace (regex, '')
}

console.log(expression1)
```

The correct regex is:

```
/(\(\ *\))+/g
```